# codeigniter error: I am trying to run my project and Select data from the datatbase but I get this error:

Tags: php, codeigniter

codeigniter errors :I am trying to run my project and Select data from the datatbase but I get this error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: controllers/NewsController.php

Line Number: 43

Controller:

```
 class NewsController extends CI_Controller{
// num of records per page
private $limit = 10;

function News(){
    parent::Controller();

    // load library
    $this->load->library(array('table','validation'));

    // load helper
    $this->load->helper('url');

    // load model
    $this->load->model('NewsModel','',TRUE);
}
function index($offset = 0){
    $this->load->model('NewsModel','',TRUE);
    // offset
    $uri_segment = 3;
    $offset = $this->uri->segment($uri_segment);

    // load data

    $News1 = $this->NewsModel->get_paged_list($this->limit, $offset)->result();

    // generate pagination
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = ('News/index/');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->NewsModel->count_all();
    $config['per_page'] = $this->limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = $uri_segment;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    // generate table data
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->table->set_empty("&nbsp;");
    $this->table->set_heading('id', 'title', 'image', 'discreption', 'Actions');
    $i = 0 + $offset;
    $newss=$this->load->model('NewsModel');
   foreach($newss as $news){
        $this->table->add_row(++$i, $news->title, $news->image,$news->discreption);
            anchor('News/view/'.$news->id,'view',array('class'=>'view')).' '.
            anchor('News/update/'.$news->id,'update',array('class'=>'update')).' '.
            anchor('News/delete/'.$news->id,'delete',array('class'=>'delete','onclick'=>"return confirm('Are you sure want to delete this person?')") );

    }
    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();

    // load view
    $this->load->view('NewsList', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
class NewsModel extends CI_Model{
// table name
private $tbl_News= 'news';

function News(){
    parent::Model();
}
// get number of News in database
function count_all(){
    return $this->db->count_all($this->tbl_News);
}
// get  with paging
function get_paged_list($limit = 10, $offset = 0){
    $this->db->order_by('id','asc');
    return $this->db->get($this->tbl_News, $limit, $offset);
}
// get News by id
function get_by_id($id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->get($this->tbl_News);
}
// add news
function save($news){
    $this->db->insert($this->tbl_News, $news);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
// update News by id
function update($id, $news){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update($this->tbl_News, $news);
}
// delete News by id
function delete($id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($this->tbl_News);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this line:

```
$newss = $this->load->model('NewsModel');
```

You need to call a `model function` here and not load the model again. I think it should be:

```
$newss = $this->NewsModel->get_paged_list();
```

Or, change the `foreach` to:

```
foreach($News1 as $news){  #$News1 from $News1 = $this->NewsModel->get_paged_list($this->limit, $offset)->result();
```

Answer (score 2):

here, you are wrong

```
 $newss=$this->load->model('NewsModel');
```

do it like this

```
 $this->load->model('NewsModel'); //this line just loads model 
$newss=$this->NewsModel->your_function_in_model(); //here you call function from models that you ve loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't know how `load->model()` works.

```
$this->load->model('NewsModel'); // will load NewsModel on NewsController
// you can call loaded model by $this->modelName
$newss = $this->NewsModel->get_paged_list(10, $i); // will call get_paged_list() on NewsModel and result will save on newss
```

There is no such function call in your code. Now you can do this `foreach($newss as $news)`

Comment: i used it Aness but i got this message 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/NewsController.php

Line Number: 45
and when i used this : foreach($News1 as $news){  #$News1 from $News1 = $this->NewsModel->get_paged_list($this->limit, $offset)->result();...i got this error message :Fatal error: Call to undefined function anchor() in C:\AppServ\www\News\application\controllers\NewsController.php on line 46

Comment: foreach($newss as $news) not $News1

Comment: $News1 = $this->NewsModel->get_paged_list($this->limit, $offset)->result();
sry you are already loading this na? then remove
$newss=$this->load->model('NewsModel'); and use foreach($News1 as $news)